# socket.gethostbyname fails

Tags: python

I am trying to read host names from a file line by line and at the same time resolve each dns name to its IP address. I am using this very simple code:

```
import socket

path = "C:\Domain\domains.txt"

f = open(path, 'r')

for line in f:
    print socket.gethostbyname(line)
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\resolve.py", line 8, in <module>
    print socket.gethostbyname(line)
gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

I did some reading and it looks like the reason for the failure is the \n carriage return. 
I tried to strip the \n in a few ways but it did not work. Can you pls help with this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html) for `gethostbyname`:

> Translate a host name to IPv4 address format. The IPv4 address is returned as a string, such as '100.50.200.5'.

And the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for error 11004 says:

> The requested name is valid and was found in the database, but it does not have the correct associated data being resolved for.

Comment: Yes the socket.gethostbyname(line) function call failes because the first entry in domains.txt was not a valid DND name when tried in a browser. I am just beginning with Python and could use a little more help. How can I check for the failure in an if statement and if failed skip to the next line in the file. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure the line is in right format?

```
for line in f:
    print repr(line)
    print socket.gethostbyname(line)
```

Comment: The function call actually failed. If what you answered was the case then it would be a different exception.